# ListView Expander issue in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox

I am using a checkbox on expander.  I want, when I check that checkbox ,it will select all rows of list view those are coming under that expander.

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

set the listview's `selectionmode` to `Multiple' or 'Extended`  and 
 on the CheckBox_Checked event you can write the code to select the rows of listview

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listview1.SelectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your checkbox_click events handler:

```
 listView1.BeginUpdate(); 
 foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
 {
     i.Selected = true;
 }

 listView1.EndUpdate();
```

Which gives you a bit more flexibility.